# Best way of running commands from inside Azure VNets?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

Sometimes, I need to test the connectivity of entities only accessible from within Azure Virtual Networks. I deploy a VM into Azure the VNet, connect to VM via ssh, and run commands to make such tests.

Do you know any other (easy, efficient, etc.) way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, that's the way to check the connectivity of the network. Since you want to check the connectivity within the Azure Virtual Network, you need to go inside the VNet. So you need to SSH into the VM to do the tests.

An easy way is that use the Azure Network Watcher. You also need to create a VM in the VNet, and the Azure Network Watcher will help you check the connectivity like below:

[image]

But the destination address must be actually listened to. For example, you want to check the connectivity from the VM to an IP address at a special port, then there must be an application or other things to listen to the IP address at the port. In this way, you do not need to SSH into the VM.